# When I scroll down in my TableView, the cell data changes - Swift 4

Tags: swift, tableview

When I scroll down in my Table View, the cell data that has disappeared then changes. How can I solve this?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var number = 1
    let finishNumber = 10

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return finishNumber
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(number)"

        number = number + 1

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update `number` every time the table view asks for a cell. That has no direct relation to the row being displayed.

It's unclear why you even have the `number` property.

If you just want to show the corresponding row number in each cell, get rid of the `number` property and update:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(number)"
```

with:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
```

Comment: That does work, however, this was just an example, I have a project filled with a lot of code and I am trying to make a bus app, the bus comes past each stop every 60 minutes. So if the time is 9:00 in the morning, I would start at that time and add an hour for each cell (indexPath.row then won't work here). Your answer is correct but how could I go with solving it for the bus app?

Comment: First, update your question so it covers your actual issue. The contrived example in your question isn't what you are really trying to do. The proper solution is to have a data model, typically an array, that contains the data you actually want to display in the table view. You use the `indexPath` to access the appropriate element of the array and setup the cell using that row's data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. However, I won't update my question, I'll just mark your answer as correct for reference to another people who come across to the issue. As soon as the 10 minutes wait time to mark a question correct is over, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question but I think you want to scroll to bottom when tableview reload right ?

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = false) {
        let section = self.numberOfSections
        if (section > 0) {
            let row = self.numberOfRows(inSection: section - 1)
            if (row > 0) {
                 self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row - 1, section: section - 1), at: .bottom, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When calling, you need to use "async"

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    yourTableView.reloadData()
    yourTableView.scrollToBottom()
}
```

Good luck.